# JAXB 2 annotation and XSD

Tags: xml, annotations, xsd, jaxb

In the JAXB 1.0 era, the recommended way of working with java object, XSD and XML is to start with XSD definition, use JAXB to generate java classes from the XSD and maintain the XSDs.

But now with JAXB 2.0 annotations, it's very convenient to generate XSDs from java classes. Is it recommended to take the approach of starting with java classes and annotations and generate XSD's?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that developers start with the object model and annotate it to get the desired XML.  This gives you more flexibility when creating your application (such as also mapping the to a database using JPA).  You only need to generate an XML schema when you want to share the structure (for example as part of a WSDL).

Check out my blog for examples of JAXB starting with model classes:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com

Comment: Right, in my case I do need to share the XSD's with consumers of the web services since the consumers can use whatever language to consume the XML messages from our web services. And the only way to share data structure is via XSDs.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say so, no. XML Schema is much richer in terms of types and certain structures, and so any schema you generate from Java are going to quite basic and unexpressive.

By all means generate a starting schema from your code, but then you should really embellish the result and maintain it as a first-class citizen, not a generated product. Once it's been fleshed out, you can plug it back in to the JAXB marshaller/unmarshaller as a validation layer.

Comment: Right, I am aware that JAXB annotations only supports a subset of all the XSD syntax and semantics. But since I am starting from code and class structure, generating XSDs to share with service consumers seems a good fit for the moment. If we are starting from schemas and schemas are more expressive than class annotations that JAXB can support, the generated classes won't be able to take advantages of the richer set of semantics.